# Python 3.3 import matplotlib in Windows don't get along

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Well I have Python 3.3 and I need **`matplotlib`** to function properly.

I used the `pip install matplotlib` to install it.

Have installed Six, dateutils, Scipy,  numpy and even pyparsing for it to work.

But when I import the function  "**`import matplotlib as mpl`**" it brings me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 2298, in <module>
    _putmask = np.putmask
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'putmask'
```

So how do I fix this?

Part of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

# custom toolbar with lorem ipsum text
class CustomToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg):
    def __init__(self,canvas_,parent_):
        self.toolitems = (
            ('Home', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'home', 'home'),
            ('Back', 'consectetuer adipiscing elit', 'back', 'back'),
            ('Forward', 'sed diam nonummy nibh euismod', 'forward', 'forward'),
            (None, None, None, None),
            ('Pan', 'tincidunt ut laoreet', 'move', 'pan'),
            ('Zoom', 'dolore magna aliquam', 'zoom_to_rect', 'zoom'),
            (None, None, None, None),
            ('Subplots', 'putamus parum claram', 'subplots', 'configure_subplots'),
            ('Save', 'sollemnes in futurum', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
            )
        NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.__init__(self,canvas_,parent_)
```

Could you please help?

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: can you also post **`print mpl.__version__`**

Comment: When I do that it gives me an error : print mpl.__version__
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3666197: Python 3, so `print(mpl.__version__)`

Comment: Your immediate problem is `numpy.putmask`. How did you install NumPy?

Comment: I installed it via Sourceforge official exe

Comment: >>> print(mpl.__version__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(mpl.__version__)
NameError: name 'mpl' is not defined

Comment: First do `import matplotlib as mpl`, then print the version.

Comment: This is my version 1.4.0

Comment: What do you get for `import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)`?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't that.. I got this C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py

Comment: Can you create an array with `numpy.array([1,2,3])`?

Comment: Yes, it creates : array([1, 2, 3])

Comment: Both `array` and `putmask` are defined in `numpy.core.multiarray`. It's weird -- almost inconceivable -- that you'd have one but not the other.